# Write result into text file in CUDA / Optix

Tags: cuda, optix

I wanted to know if it was possible to write a text file of variables calculated in my program Cuda / Optix. That's variables are in my .cu files and therefore can not be written by the CPU.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, it's not possible to perform file I/O from a CUDA kernel.  You would need to use `cudaMemcpy` and copy the data back to host memory, and from there you can write the values to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Optix, but as far as I know, there is no way to write to a file from CUDA. You should download your values to the host in order to store them to a file.

You can use `cudaMemcpy( dstPointer, srdPointer, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);` to copy data from the device (GPU) to the host (CPU). See: [NVIDIA CUDA Library: cudaMemcpy](http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp422/resources/cuda/html/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g48efa06b81cc031b2aa6fdc2e9930741.html)
Be aware that your `dstPointer` has to be the large enought to store the data!

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answers suggest, it's not possible to write data to a file through CUDA kernels. If your code involves multiple loops, you might be thinking how slow your program would be to transfer and write data on each loop; if so, you should make your data transfer after a given number of loops. In other words, write the file in chunks of multiple loops, not on every single loop.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really understand what you want to say. What do you mean by 'loop'? Kernel runs? I would say that the fequency of data output depends on what **Emmanuel** wants to do. Please clarify your answer. Also, punctuation might help... ;-)

Comment: All I'm trying to say is that if the kernel is executed through multiple loops and you need to write a certain variable or set of variables to a file, and that variable's value is updated in each loop, you should just write it in chunks of multiple loops, not in every single loop, to spare your code the transfer time (i.e. write x(1:1000) through a single transfer & write, instead of transfer & writing each x(i)), this is useful if the no. of loops is too high, and you need to monitor the variable's behavior and not wait for the entire loops to finish, it's a minor hint, not a big deal

Answer (score 0):

in optix, you can transfer all your data back to host using buffer, once it is downloaded back to HOST memory you can easily convert the data in csv or txt format

Answer (score 0):

I do not know a way to open a file descriptor and write to it directly from the device; however, I have used `rtPrintf`[1](https://raytracing-docs.nvidia.com/optix_6_0/api_6_0/html/group__rt_printf.html) in OptiX to **redirect the output of a program to a file**. `rtPrintf` will allow you to print the contents of variables, etc, and if you prefix your prints with a keyword, you can `grep` for specific items easily. This strategy is a good way to debug early stage OptiX code and even trace what it is doing to some degree.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot open a file in your device code; you can do printf()'s to the console for debugging (in either optix or cuda, doesn't matter), but cannot open or write to files.

Probably the easiest solution is to create some CUDA managed memory (cudaMallocManaged()) that can be read and written on both host and device; write your variable values into that on the device, then afterward open a file and dump them on the host. This also works on both cuda and optix.